# Two commuting weights in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\varphi$ be a faithful weight on $M$. $\psi$ is a weight commuting with $\varphi$.

In Takesaki's book, Vol 2, Chapter VIII , Proposition 3.15. The author mentions that $\psi \varphi=\varphi \psi$ is equivalent to $\psi=\psi\circ \sigma_t^{\varphi}$.

How to derive the above conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation $\psi=\psi\circ\sigma_t^\varphi$ is how Takesaki defines "$\psi$ commuting with $\varphi$".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1495807)

Comment: In what sense is this "not an answer"? What would the answer be? The author defines $\varphi\psi=\psi\varphi$ as $\psi=\psi\circ\sigma^\varphi_t$.

Comment: I mean how to conclude $\varphi \psi=\psi\varphi$ from $\sigma_\varphi^t(x)=\Delta_\varphi^{it} x \Delta_\varphi^{-it}$ and $\psi=\psi\circ\sigma^\varphi_t$?

Comment: There is no obvious meaning for $\varphi\psi$, what would the product of weights be? As I said in the answer, Takesaki **defines** "$\psi$ commutes with $\varphi$''  to mean $\psi=\psi\circ\sigma_t^\varphi$.

Comment: I thought $\varphi\psi(x):=\varphi(x)\psi(x)$, I made a mistake.